# Login to su and take the password from the same script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sudo, su

I'm trying to automate the build process which is done on linux server.
to do that first i need to login to the su and then perform the tasks for stopping and starting the server. I've written shell script to do that but there are some problems I'm facing,

1) even though I'm providing password from script using expect & send it tasks for password on terminal.

2) doing `echo'password' | sudo -S su` takes password automatically but says wrong even if it is right.

3) **and when i put the password through terminal manually using  `su` I get logged in to the su but the rest of the commands in script does not gets executed unless i do exit.**

The script I've tried is,

```
echo 'password\n' | sudo -S su ##it says wrong password for su
commands to be performed after logging to su
exit
```

I've tried expect and send too,

```
su expect"Password" send "password\n";
and rest of the code here
```

but it's not fetching password from send automatically, I've to put it manually.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this!!

Comment: In your script, use sudo instead of su.

Comment: but that says "sorry, try again" which means its considering the password as wrong password though its correct.

Comment: `sudo` requires *your* password, not the superuser's password.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` requires the password of the user calling it, not the password of the superuser (or the user specified by the `-u` option). That may seem backwards, but the idea is that `sudo` can be configured to provide fine-grained control over what you are actually allowed to run as the superuser, rather than giving you access to the superuser account itself. Also, `sudo` keeps a log of who does what for auditing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the wrong password, use the right password instead.  Like others have already commented, `sudo` requires your password, not root's.

Additionally, your script is wrong.  The sequence `su; echo hello; exit` will run a root shell with `su`, then *when that shell exits,*  run `echo hello` and `exit` in your current shell.

You want this instead:

```
sudo -S sh -c 'echo hello'
```

The `su` is completely superfluous because `sudo` already takes care of switching to the `root` user, and offers a more convenient syntax for running commands as another user to boot.  The `sh -c '...'` isn't strictly required in this example, but will probably be useful if you have more than one command which you wish to execute using elevated privileges.  (Make sure you understand the implications.  A useful commandment is to try to run even less code as `sudo` than you currently do.  Always.)

Comment: I've tried user password too and the result is still same !

Comment: The command `echo 'password\n'` will print your password followed by the literal characters `\n`. You are apparently hoping for a newline, but you don't need one here; and anyway, `echo` provides one by default, so you don't need to ask for one.